# CSS Styles not rendering for Angular View in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-view, ngroute

I have an angular app that is working well except in IE8.  Essentially, my styles from the external stylesheet are not taking effect on code that is rendered inside of my view.  I've followed the Angular IE guide.  Here is the code I have on my html element:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>         
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" xmlns:ng='http://angularjs.org' id='ng-app' ng-app='HPApp' ng-controller='HPMainController' ng-init='loadHP()'> 
<![endif]-->
```

I later render an IE specific stylesheet, otherwise I use data binding to render a stylsheet specific to the URL

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="css/{{cssPath}}">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Later in the body of my html I have a div with a ng-view attribute

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

If I delete the div with ng-view and hardcode in my template my styles take effect.  Otherwise, my styles seem to be applied to the page before the template is rendered.

Also, note that if I use the ng-href attribute on my IE specific stylesheet, IE will not load it at all.

Comment: Having done a bit of work with getting IE8 and AngularJS to play nice, I can at least suggest that IE8 is a lot more temperamental about poorly formed HTML especially in conjunction with nesting templates like with ng-view or other methods. I had a few cases where very odd things were not working only in IE8 just to eventually figure out it was because I made an html mistake (unclosed tag, self-closing a tag that is not allowed to self-close, etc)

Comment: I've had to use $.trim with all templates and IE8

Comment: @Rich have you experimented with the ng-view onload attribute? Do you think that could somehow reload my CSS after the template has rendered?

Comment: Sorry I have not, I do templating a bit differently due to specific requirements. Although what I was saying is more along the lines that if this case is similar to my issues, the CSS doesn't need to be reloaded but rather that some malformed HTML is preventing the already loaded CSS from being applied properly. Search also brings up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556102/angular-and-ie8-html5-elements-not-styled-inside-ng-view?rq=1  . Which reminds me I had to include the html5shiv to support HTML5 tags in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
document.createElement('ng-view');
```

to your index file ?

[angular doc p.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)